# Json schema for array of objects doesn't validate

Tags: arrays, json, jsonschema

I have this schema for a json response

```
{
    "title": "Products",
    "description": "schema for products",
    "type": "array",
    "properties": {
        "id": {
            "description": "id of a product",
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "name": {
            "description": "name of the product",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "created_at": {
            "description": "record created_at",
            "type": "string",
            "format": "date-time"
        },
        "updated_at": {
            "description": "record updated_at",
            "type": "string",
            "format": "date-time"
        }
    },
    "required": ["id", "name"]
}
```

and I want to match this schema with this json

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Cricket Ball"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Soccer Ball"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "football ball"
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Basketball ball"
}, {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Table Tennis ball"
}, {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Tennis ball"
}]
```

This schema matches the response but it also matches the schema in which the required field is this

```
"required": ["ids", "names"]
```

I think the schema is validated against the array and the objects in the array are not validated.

Comment: Its very unclear what you are actually doing. Include the controller and the view (if you are using jbuilder) or the serializer if you are using AMS.

Comment: this isn't related to rails. removed the rails tag in the recent edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you have it set up now, your `properties` key refers to the array itself, not to each item, and is being ignored (because arrays don't have properties, they just have items).  You need to use the `items` key to validate each item in the array, like so:

```
{
    "title": "Products",
    "description": "schema for products",
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "id": {
            "description": "id of a product",
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "name": {
            "description": "name of the product",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "created_at": {
            "description": "record created_at",
            "type": "string",
            "format": "date-time"
        },
        "updated_at": {
            "description": "record updated_at",
            "type": "string",
            "format": "date-time"
        }
      },
      "required": ["id", "name"]
    }
}
```

Comment: PS The [json scheme validator](http://www.jsonschemavalidator.net) is a great way to test schemas out live.

Comment: that did it. awesome

Comment: I tried [the schema validator](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/) but purposefully change the **second object** in the sample JSON data array, changing "id" to "id2", but the page says "no errors found".  How do we make the validator validates the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc. object as well?

Comment: Why is the following json not giving validation errors against your schema?
[{
    "id": "1",
    "name": 2
}, {
    "id": "3"
}]

Answer (score 0):

try `map`

```
new_array = response.map{ |k| { 'id': k['properties']['id']['description'], 'name': k['properties']['name']['description'] } }
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not exactly what I asked. I don't want the first one be converted to the second one. I want to match [json-schema](http://json-schema.org/)